# JQuery - Do this if you're NOT .hover this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

```
cardh = 0

$('.cardgreen > img').hover(function () {
    if (cardh == 0) {
        $('.card > img').animate({ height: 150, width: 193, opacity: '1', left: 0, top: 9 }, 500);
        $('.anfahrtlink').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 500).animate({ width: 0 }, 0);
        $('.cardgreen > img').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 500).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);
        cardh = 1
    }
});

$('.cardgreen > img').notanymore().hover(function () {
    if (cardh == 1) {
        $('.cardgreen > img').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 300);
        $('.anfahrtlink').animate({ width: 84 }, 0).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);
        $('.card > img').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 300).animate({ opacity: '0', width: 0, height: 0, left: 194, top: 75}, 270);
        cardh = 0
    }
});
```

How to say JQuery: DO THE 2nd thing when you're not hovering the div > img anymore..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second function you pass to [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is the `mouseleave` handler, like this:

```
$('.cardgreen > img').hover(function() {
  $('.card > img').animate({height: 150, width: 193, opacity: '1', left: 0, top: 9},500)
  $('.anfahrtlink').animate({opacity: '0',},500).animate({width:0},0);
  $('.cardgreen > img').animate({opacity: '0'},500)
                       .animate({opacity: '1'},500);
}, function() {
    $('.cardgreen > img').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
    $('.anfahrtlink').animate({width:84},0).animate({opacity: '1',},500)
    $('.card > img').animate({opacity: '1'},300)
                    .animate({opacity: '0', width: 0, height: 0, left:194, top:75},270);
});
```

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes 2 handlers - for [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), or like you had, a single handler that does *both*.  But since you want hover "in and out" behavior...use the 2 handler version.

Comment: @Mr.Freeman - that shouldn't be the case, do you have an example page?

Answer (score 2):

the jQuery `.hover()` method can take 2 arguments (see here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

handlerIn(eventObject) - A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
handlerOut(eventObject) - A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.